# Why getting empty list while try to get links which includes specific class in python using bs4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm try to get some links which are includes specific class, therefore i writed this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getPages(requestedURLS):
    _buff = []

    for url in requestedURLS:
        try:
            _buff.append(requests.get(url))
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print(err)
    return _buff

def getProductList(pages):
    links = []
    for page in pages:
        content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        links.extend(content.find_all("a", class_="sresult lvresult clearfix li shic"))
        print(links)


def main():
    pageLinks = [
        "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ssn=carabaeuro13&_clu=2&_fcid=3&_localstpos=&_stpos=&gbr=1&_pppn=r1&scp=ce0",
        "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ssn=carabaeuro13&_clu=2&_fcid=3&_localstpos=&_stpos=&gbr=1&_pgn=2&_skc=200&rt=nc",
        "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ssn=carabaeuro13&_clu=2&_fcid=3&_localstpos=&_stpos=&gbr=1&_pgn=3&_skc=400&rt=nc"
    ]

    #Results in : <div id="Results" class="results "> <ul id="ListViewInner">
    pages = getPages(pageLinks)
    productList = getProductList(pages)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can check links there are lots of links which includes this class but output is empty as you see in below:

```
C:\Users\projects\getMarketData\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/projects/getMarketData/getData.py
[]
[]
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: There is no `<a>` tag with `sresult lvresult clearfix li shic` class, perhaps you meant `<li>` ?

Comment: Thanks i missed that. But when i change <a> tag with <li> it doesn't give me entire tags which has this class.

Comment: Are you looking to get links that are within <li> tag?

Comment: Yes, there are products' pages' links in <li> tags and i'm trying to get those links

Comment: if you want to use this class then you have to search `<li>` and later use `find_all('a')` to search links inside every `<li>` separatelly - with `for`-loop. Or you can use other methods to search like xpath selector `xpath('//li[@class="sresult lvresult clearfix li shic"]//a")` or css selector `select("li.sresult.lvresult.clearfix.li.shic a")`

Comment: when I check page in browser then I see `<a class="vip" ...>` so maybe you should use class `vip` to search directly links.

Comment: @furas I did that but i get 50 links out of 200 links when i changed that line to this ```links.extend(content.find_all("a", class_="vip"))```

Comment: maybe page uses JavaScript to add items. `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: BTW:  as default page display only `50` items. For other items you would have to go to next page or you would have to use `_ipg=200` in url.

Comment: How can i get all links, my purpose is getting all products from a store on ebay?

Comment: check url for to pages and you will see which element in url changed page - I expect it will be `_pgn=2` - so I would use `for`-loop for test. Later you can search link in button `">"` to get url to next page.

Comment: Have you tried using headers? Use at least the `User-Agent` header. Keep the network tab of the developer tools open while you're sending a request through a browser. That'll show the headers that the browser is sending. Copy that and paste it in your code. So your request statement will look like this: `r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla...', ...other headers...})`.

Answer (score 0):

Using appropriate headers should do the trick:

```
url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ssn=carabaeuro13&_clu=2&_fcid=3&_localstpos=&_stpos=&gbr=1&_pppn=r1&scp=ce0'
request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.ebay.co.uk',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'sresult lvresult clearfix li shic'})
```

Result:

```
print(len(items)) # 18
print(items[0]['listingid']) # 333200565336
```

Use the network tab of the developer tools to inspect the traffic. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) out if you've never done this before.

Comment: Why using this header?

Comment: @No_0n3 these are the headers that my browser sends when I fetch the ebay page. If you don't customize these when sending a request programmatically (through `requests` in Python), the website will identify your script as a bot (which it is) and probably block it after a while. To avoid that, we'll mimic the browser and send the headers so that our bot appears like a browser.